# How can I make my scriptable EXE delete itself?

Tags: windows, batch-file, uninstall

I am attempting to make a custom "uninstaller script" using a batch file that will delete specified files, then delete itself after all is said and done. My goal is to make a script that can be converted to EXE format as well.  Here is my **base** script:

```
rmdir "%DIRECTORYPATH%" /s /q
del "%FILEPATH%" /s /q
(goto) 2>nul & del "%~f0"
```

With this script, I can get the batch file to delete itself, but not after converting it into executable format with F2KO Software's [Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php). I have tinkered with the settings before compiling the output, but nothing seems to work. The purpose of converting my script to this format is so that I can set a custom icon and version information.

I have even declared set paths in my script, converted it, wrapped the exe in an SFX archive, and set it to extract and run from %TEMP% with no success. The SFX module binds the EXE and doesn't allow self-deletion. I attempted to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19748576) method (originally from [@Samy Bencherif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1727470/samy-bencherif)) to get around the SFX module running in the background, but this also didn't work:

```
rmdir "%DIRECTORYPATH%" /s /q
del "%FILEPATH%" /s /q
process.start("cmd /c ping localhost -n 3 > nul & del "%TARGETPATH%")
taskkill /%TARGET%.exe
```

The list of attempts goes on. I have tried every thing I know, and have been searching for some time now with no fruition. Any help is *greatly* appreciated.

Comment: [Self-deleting programs are very hard to accomplish on Windows.](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/self-deleting-executables).

Comment: If you're happy to wait until next reboot, you could create a new registry entry in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce` which calls the delete command to remove the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution... have the executable create a batchfile that deletes it.

```
echo %CD:~0,2% >> delme.bat
echo cd %~dp0 >> delme.bat
echo del /f MYAPP.exe >> delme.bat
echo echo y^| del /f "%FILEPATH%" >> delme.bat
echo exit >> delme.bat
start %~dp0\delme.bat
exit
```

Replace MYAPP.exe with your exe.
The batch file will also delete itself...

Answer (score 0):

Aim to the file location then>

DEL App.exe

Comment: Already tried that.